# cassandra Whether tables can be configured

Tags: cassandra

I want to configure a table in cassandra like this：

```
CREATE TABLE users (
                 user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
                 first varchar,
                 last varchar,
                 age int
               ) WITH syncEs=true;
```

So I modified the source code to add a syncEs property.

Although it has been stored in tables under system_schema.

But on a 3-node cluster, we still don't get the correct values.

There's only one node that gets the correct value,

Hard to understand the source code of friends, tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there must be some other place in the code that determines the list of table properties to replicate.

A better solution here might be to make use of the table properties that already exist.  For instance, the `comment` property goes largely unused.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    first varchar,
    last varchar,
    age int
) WITH comment='syncEs=true';
```

This works, and you can modify/read this property in the same way that you would any other table property.  And this one *will* replicate.

Otherwise, if you're modifying the source of Cassandra to support custom table properties, you're going to be largely on your own.